# reading data from a .txt file and saving to a vector

Tags: c++

This is a very simple question: How can I read .txt file and save to a vector using c++? I've 9 data stored in a txt file separated by tab and I want to save this to three different Vector (I'm using Eigen library).
the 9 data are this:

```
 -468.01    198.74  -123.9  -471.67 195.41  46.878  -471.39 111.84  45.518
```

Someone can help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to store them into a vector of doubles, and you have an ifstream object the simplest way is:

```
std::ifstream ifs( "data.txt" );

std::vector< double > values;
double val;
while( ifs >> val )
   values.push_back( val );
```

There is an alternative using istream_iterator:

```
std::copy( std::istream_iterator<double>(ifs), std::istream_iterator<double>(),
          std::back_inserter( values ) );
```

This saves into a single vector (not 3). The title says save into a vector, the text of the question asks you to save into 3 vectors. It's difficult to know how you want to format the data into your 3 vectors.

Of course you could read them from the file into a single vector and have a wrapper class that makes the one vector appear as 3 sub-ranges.

I've given you the basics and please try the rest of the coding yourself.

Comment: I'm using infile.open() function but I don't know how to say "skip the tab and take the next value". With eigen is simple to pass the returned value like: vector(0)=acquired value.

Comment: The whitespace is skipped with streaming, i.e. using >> to write into a double value. I also showed you ways to read that will populate a std::vector. It is for you to work out how it fits in with your EigenVector library.

Comment: @CashCow Could you please show me how this would be extended to read in a matrix? Thanks :)!