# Reading data from .txt file and saving into multiple vectors using c++

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a data.txt file that contains data like this:

```
1.0 0.5 1.5 0.01761
2.0 1.5 2.5 0.01977
3.0 2.5 3.5 0.02185
```

I am trying to read the data.txt file and storing the numbers in the individual columns into different vectors. For example, the 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0 of the left-most column will go into a `vector<double> w`, 0.5, 1.5 and 2.5 in the second column will go into `vector<double> x`. The remaining 2 columns will go into `vector<double> y` and `vector<double> z` respectively.

I have read other replies to similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686604/reading-data-from-a-txt-file-and-saving-to-a-vector) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151922/reading-a-txt-text-file-in-c-containing-float-separated-by-space). However, they do not address the issue of storing data from different columns into different vectors.

The following is my current attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace::std;

int main()
{
    FILE *f_read;
    double my_variable = 0;
    vector<double> w, x, y, z;
    f_read= fopen("data.txt", "r");

    for(int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
    {
        fscanf(f_read, "%.lf", &my_variable);
        w[i] = my_variable;
        fscanf(f_read, "%.lf", &my_variable);
        x[i] = my_variable;
        fscanf(f_read, "%.lf", &my_variable);
        y[i] = my_variable;
        fscanf(f_read, "%.lf", &my_variable);
        z[i] = my_variable;
    }

    //the following loop is printed to verify the vectors are correctly filled
    for(int j = 0; j <=3; ++j)
    {
        cout << "The " << j << "th value in w is " << w[j] << endl;
        cout << "The " << j << "th value in x is " << x[j] << endl; 
        cout << "The " << j << "th value in y is " << y[j] << endl;
        cout << "The " << j << "th value in z is " << z[j] << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

However, the last "for" loop was never printed and the program returned -1073741819. My guess is something is wrong with how I fill the vectors in the first loop, but I am unable to see where my error is.

I will appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Your vectors don't have a size allocated for them, so you cant use indexing `[]` to assign the contents. Either use `push_back()` or first `resize()` space for them.

Comment: @acraig5075 You mean `resize()`, not `reserve()`. Reserve allocates memory and increases the capacity, it does not change the actual size of the vector. You should still use push_back when using reserve. You can also specify the size as argumen to each vector's constructor (i.e. `vector<double> w(3)`)

Comment: @Athosvk Of course, thank you.

Comment: Will your data file always contain only three rows?

Comment: Also i would recommend to use `c++` IO operations (`std::cin` for reading)

Comment: You might be reading double value in to a float for last for loop.

Comment: @acraig5075 opps!! I am new to C++ and I was under the (erroneous) impression that it is not required to allocate a size for vectors, unlike arrays in C.

To answer your question, no my data has 80 rows in total, but I am just using the first 3. I will then extend my code to include all the 80 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing beyond the end of your `vector`s, they are all empty. As you know the number of rows you are dealing with, you can initialise them with the correct size.

You can then read directly into the `vector`'s elements

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> w(3), x(3), y(3), z(3);
    std::ifstream f_read("data.txt");

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        f_read >> w[i] >> x[i] >> y[i] >> z[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If instead you don't know the number of rows, you can read into values and `push_back`

```
    for(double w_, x_, y_, z_; f_read >> w_ >> x_ >> y_ >> z_; )
    {
        w.push_back(w_);
        x.push_back(x_);
        y.push_back(y_);
        z.push_back(z_);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Caleth! Works like a charm now!